# IMEI Invalid - Lenovo S860, rooted android 4.4.2, nothing works

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, lenovo, imei

I saw and tried more than 10 ways to repair the IMEI, including rooting the phone, connection to PC, mobile terminal emulator, but nothing works.

The phone is 2GB RAM Lenovo S860. It has 2 sim card slots (I'm using both) 3G and 2G respectively. (I cannot post link because of low reputation, gsmarena has specifications for my phone)

I accidentally deleted the system folder, after which the phone bricked, but I managed to repair it using the following android verion (http://www.needrom.com/download/rom-stock-4-4/) as an upgrade to (http://www.needrom.com/download/lenovo-s860/), both installed using PC.

Now I have the IMEI problem and I really need quick fix because I need the phone for work.

Comment: If you want to get a suggestion you haven't already tried, you should list all the things you've tried already, not just a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [MTK Engineering Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.themonsterit.EngineerStarter) app from Play Store to restore my lost IMEI after flashing ROM. You should know your previous IMEI number. It is usually mentioned in the area underneath battery. When you will open your phone you will see it.

Steps:

1. Open MTK Engineering Mode.
2. Click MTK setting.
3. From connectivity tab choose CDS information, radio information, phone1 or phone2, send AT command AT+EGMR=1,7,”your15digitsIMEI”.
4. Click send AT command button.
5. Restart your phone and it should work now.

If still unclear see my article [here](http://yunarwinardi.com/imei-lost-after-flash-rom-on-android-phones-or-tablet/).

Answer (score 0):

1) I installed the following android verion http://www.needrom.com/download/lenovo-s860/, but it upgrades to a chinese Vibe 2.0, which is very customised and has no Google Play Store, as weall as all other Google apps.

2) So I used the "[Upgrade Firmware](http://iskyblog.blogspot.com/)" option on the PC program (SP Flash Tool) instead of the "Download" one to install http://www.needrom.com/download/rom-stock-4-4/ (this site contains very precise instructions, check it out before doing any of the steps)

3) Now phone works perfectly, but it has IMEI connection problems - IMEI Invalid - Lenovo S860, rooted android 4.4.2, nothing works

4) KingoROOT seems to fix the IMEI problem

5) Phone up and running perfectly